# Flask while i reset password its not decrypting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having the below code written in Model.py

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    slunetid = db.Column(db.String(length=100),nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(length=100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=1000))
    group = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False)

    @property
    def password_hash(self):
        return self.password_hash

    @password_hash.setter
    def password_hash(self, plain_text_password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')
```

In the route.py

```
@app.route('/forgot_password', methods =['GET','POST'])
def forgot_password():
    form = PasswordReset()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        slunet_id_attempted = User.query.filter_by(slunetid = form.slunet_id.data).first()
        print(f'The slunet id value is {slunet_id_attempted.slunetid}')
        
        if slunet_id_attempted and slunet_id_attempted.check_password_correction(
                attempted_password=form.old_password.data
        ):
            slunet_id_attempted.password_hash = form.password2.data
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
```

When i go and check after password field after reset its not in encrypted format. Instead its in plain text. While the same call is working while creating user.

Registeration code below.

```
app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
#@login_required
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Inside register commit ")
        user_to_create = User(slunetid=form.slunet_id.data,
                              email = form.email_address.data,
                              password_hash = form.password.data,
                              name = form.name.data,
                              group = form.group.data,
                              active = form.active.data)
        print("Inside register commit ")
        db.session.add(user_to_create)
        db.session.commit()
```

Not sure what i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def password_hash(self):
    return self.password

@password_hash.setter
def password_hash(self, plain_text_password):
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')
```

try this